# Each have or Have each

Tags: grammar, quantifiers

Good day, people.
The question aims to elucidate **the correct position of "EACH"** in relation to the following sentences:

What is the correct order?

> They **have each** won University Challenge on four occasions - more than
> any other institution. **(sounds fine to me)**

> They **each have** won University Challenge on four occasions - more than
> any other institution.

Also

> "The houses **were each** cleaned." **(sounds fine to me)**

> "The houses **each were** cleaned."

Comment: The last two are oddities.  One expects something after "each cleaned": The houses were **each cleaned** with an industrial vacuum.

Comment: "Each" is a quantificational adjunct functioning in clause structure. This is evident from the fact that when the verb is an auxiliary it _preferentially_ follows rather than precedes it, as in your examples 1. and 3.

Comment: *We **all were** chosen* and *They **each were** rewarded* are "poetic, literary" resequenced versions of the idiomatically standard *We **were all** chosen* and *They **were each** rewarded*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [1] *They have each won University Challenge on four occasions - more than*
> *any other institution*.
>
> [2] *They each have won University Challenge on four occasions - more than*
> *any other institution.*
>
> [3] *The houses were each cleaned.*
>
> [4] *The houses each were cleaned.*

Here, "each" is a quantificational adjunct functioning in clause structure. This is evident from the fact that when the verb is an auxiliary it *preferentially* follows rather than precedes it, as in [1] and [3].

The same applies to "all" and "both". For example, *We had* *both/all enjoyed it* is preferable to *We both*/*all had enjoyed it*.

Comment: Great answer, BillJ! It's a little clearer now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your first sentence is the correct one. As for the last two, *Each of the houses was cleaned* or *Each house was cleaned* would be more natural.

Comment: Actually, I'd remove a point for 3 or 4 in an essay unless it were something like: The houses were each cleaned with a large sponge. [haha]

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the second sentence.

Comment: @Lambie You're too tough, man! ahaha. Thank you all.

Comment: @Lambie Why can't I say "The houses were each cleaned." by itself? But: "The houses were each cleaned with a large sponge." Unfortunately it's not very clear to me.

Comment: You can say it but as I said the ear expects something after it. Because normally one would say: Each house was cleaned or each of the houses was cleaned. What I wrote exemplifies the **expectation I am explaining**. The dogs were each fed a bowl of dry food. The boys were each given a piece of paper. The houses were each cleaned with an industrial vacuum. Would you normally: As cases se limparam cada uma? Same idea here.

Comment: Hahaha, I didn't expect some Portuguese. It's clearer now, Lambie.
If you need anything in Portuguese, let me know XD

Thank you